# How to pass dhcp details of my local network in my vagrant file

Tags: configuration, vagrant, dhcp

I have a vagrant file, where the IP of my virtual box is hardcoded.

```
# The IP address of the first server
primary_ip = "172.17.8.101"
```

I wanted to dynamically assign the ip based on my local network (corporate network).

In vagrant documentation, I see we can use

The easiest way to use a private network is to allow the IP to be assigned via DHCP.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html

In the same vagrant file, during the configuration I see that the hardcoded ip is referred. Now since, I am using the 'type: dhcp', how can I pass the IP details for the below configuration?

```
host.vm.provision :shell, inline: %Q|echo 'export ETCD_AUTHORITY="#{primary_ip}:2379"' >> /home/vagrant/.profile|
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code snippet so that the virtualbox is depends on the host network to get IP address.

```
config.vm.network "public_network",
      use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true, bridge:
```

While running my vagrant file, I had the below bridged network interfaces. To auto select the network interface used the below code snippet.

```
Available bridged network interfaces:
1) Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
2) VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
3) VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
```

code snippet.

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection"
```